# Signing package with dpkg-buildpackage fails but succeeds with debsign

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I have the following gpg key:

```
-----------------------------
pub   2048R/F516F2E7 2017-06-19
uid                  Ulad Kasach <email@provider.com>
sub   2048R/4057A05F 2017-06-19
```

When I attempt to create and sign a package with `dpkg-buildpackage -kF516F2E7 -S -sa`, I get the following error:

```
gpg: skipped "F516F2E7": No secret key
gpg: dpkg-sign.1F6Q4CLd/<package name>.dsc: clearsign failed: No secret key

dpkg-buildpackage: error: failed to sign .dsc and .changes file
```

However, if I run `debsign -k F516F2E7 <package name>.dsc`
It succeeds.

Does anyone know why this could be and how `dpkg-buildpackage` can be made to succeed?

Answer (score 16):

I was having this same issue until now.

`dpkg-buildpackage` seems to expect you to pass an email address along with the -k flag rather than the key ID.

```
dpkg-buildpackage -kmyemail@mydomain.com
```

After this i had no errors.

Comment: Passing the email to -k is something I didn't think of doing, thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, I tried signing it separately to no avail. An strace revealed that it was looking for the buildinfo in a temp directory.

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
sudo debuild -b -uc -us
```

That command generates an unsigned deb files for local use.

Comment: I used the -uc -us flags from this post and did: sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc -us   Does this do the same as debuild?

Comment: @qwerty9967 is the same, based in this man site:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html - 
"-us, --unsigned-source" and "-uc, --unsigned-changes"

Comment: use `sudo dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc -us` was the solution for me

Answer (score 5):

While this does not answer the question of "why `dpkg-buildpackage` fails", by replacing `dpkg-buildpackage` with `debuild` (`debuild` accepts `dpkg-buildpackage` arguments) the intended result can be had.

tl;dr: "str.replace" `dpkg-buildpackage` with `debuild` for a quick solution

Comment: debuild successes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't import your private key. Try to import it:

```
gpg --import private-key-file.gpg
```